# Turning previous code into a string in C# like coldfusions cfsavecontent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, coldfusion

I am converting an old application written in ColdFusion 5 into C#. Specifically MVC 3 with Razor engine. A problem I have run into is that the previous team who wrote the application used `<cfsavecontent>` which turns all code until closed into a variable that can be read later, from what I can understand. My question is:
How can I turn this:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="myVar">
 <!--- 300 lines of code making tables --->
</cfsavecontent>

<cfset myVar = ReplaceNocase(myVar, someCode, otherCode)>
```

into something equivelant in MVC 3?

Comment: Would probably be better to instead look at what the goal of doing so was than trying to find a 1:1 replacement of it. Generally that would simply mean building a string in this case, but that may not be the best way to solve the problem in your new language..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Verbatim Literal String in c# instead of the cfsavecontent:

```
String myVar = @"

300 lines of code making tables

";
```

if you have variables being evaluated in the cfsavecontent before you find and replace, then look at this article:

http://blog.luckyus.net/2009/02/03/heredoc-in-c-sharp/